# Visual Studio: Undo-redo of replace-action does not scroll editor window

Tags: visual-studio-2012, replace, undo-redo, visual-web-developer-2010

I did some find-and-replace actions in my C++ code with visual studio:

- only single find-and-replace actions (did not use “replace all”)
- only one file affected (did not change multiple files at the same time)
- thus, a very simple case!

Then I wanted to undo these changes. So I pressed ctrl-Z one time. This had the desired effect. The latest change (which was still visible in the current screen) was undone.

But I also wanted to undo the remaining changes. These changes where currently not visible on the screen. So I expected the editor to scroll there when pressing ctrl-Z.

But unfortunately the editor did not scroll to the position of the undo when I pressed ctrl-z.

The undo worked, however. I checked by scrolling to the position manually.

Then I tried it with redo. Same result: Redo worked, but the editor did not scroll to the position of the redo.

Finally I tried if this also happens when I undo-redo other types of changes (not made by the “find and replace” functionality).
Result: Undo-Redo worked correctly and also scrolled correctly!

Thus: It seems only changes by the “find and replace” functionality are affected by this problem.

Did you also have this problem and found a solution?

Please help me!

Regards Gerhard

Comment: This question already got me the [tumbleweed](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed?userid=2388926)-badge! Is there really nobody who can help me?

Comment: I see the same problem on Visual Studio 2012 Express, and Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.

Answer (score -1):

I am having the same thing happen in Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 (Version 11.0.60610.01 Update 3).

It might sound like it's not that important, but it is really hurting the usability of this otherwise great IDE!

PS I've been using VS since the 90s, I still haven't found anything better.  I wish MS would put macros back into VS, even if it's VBA (or Python)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't post an answer that is a comment. Take a look at the about page http://stackoverflow.com/about